# Getting the filtered data extension associated with a send and it's corresponding definition

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions

I am looking for a way to extract the following information programmatically:

1. For each job ID, what is the corresponding Data Extensions that was used for sending

[image]

2. For that data extension, what is the filtering conditions used to create it

[image]

I have tried using both Data View and Tracking Extract tables but cannot find this information stored anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, you likely won't be able to programmatically pull the historic information easily as the [_Sent data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5) only gives you the `ListId` for the audience and you are sending to a data extension.

But what you can do going forward is to enable [Send Logging](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_email_sendlogging_de.htm&type=5) and include the `_DataSourceName` which will give you the data extension name:

> This value captures any audience object sent to. This covers lists,
>   data extensions, groups, and filters.

Alternatively, you can also use an [UpsertDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertde.htm) within the email to populate your own data extension.

For #2, the only advice I have is to convert your filter to a [SQL query activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_the_sql_query_activity.htm&type=5), as filters can be difficult to manage.